# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'List'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to do a project, and this project has lists, each with a title, and when I use Map, I have this error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'List'
```

How can I solve the problem?

And this file shows all the lists and each list has been passed a title.

lists.tsx:

```
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import SingleList from "./single-list";
import { useStyle } from "../../../../styles/list-styles";
import Header from "../../header-footer/header";
import ListModal from "../modals/list-modal";
import { List } from "../../../../redux-store/reducers/todo-list-reducer";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Lists = () => {
  const classes = useStyle();

  // TS infers type: (state: RootState) => object
  const selectListData = (state: List) => state;

  // TS infers `lists` is object
  const lists = useSelector(selectListData);
  console.log("title-listData: ", lists);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />

      <Grid className={classes.grid}>
        <Grid
          container
          className={classes.addButton}
          item
          direction="row-reverse"
        >
          <ListModal />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item lg={12} direction="row" spacing={1}>
          {lists.map((list: { title: string; }) => (
            <Grid item lg={3} sm={6} xs={12}>
              <SingleList title={list.title} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default Lists;
```

Comment: what output are you getting in ` console.log("title-listData: ", lists);`

Comment: export interface List {
  title?: string;
  id?: number;
  tasks?: Task[];
}

------------------
must print id, title, tasks[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for a check value of `lists`. Array values available or not in the `lists` variable. `lists` is must be an Array format.

Or you cal also check with `{Array.isArray(lists) && lists.length && lists.map( ...`

```
      {lists?.map((list: { title: string; }) => (
        <Grid item lg={3} sm={6} xs={12}>
          <SingleList title={list.title} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
```